# sending ajax value into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have 2 tables : 'excel'[image] and 'request' [image]

I get the value from input text and now i want to send the '9000' value into 'tarif' field in 'excel' table.

[image]

this is my controller :

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

 function edit($excel_id, $tarif)
 {
  echo $excel_id;
  $this->load->model('request');
  $this->request->updatedata($tarif,$excel_id);

 }
}
```

my model:

```html
<?php
class Request extends CI_Model {

 function updatedata($id,$tarif) 
   {
        $this->db->set('tariff', $tarif);
        $this->db->where('excel_id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->update('excel');
        return $query->result_array();
   }
}
```

this is my ajax, inside the view:

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Admin Kirim Undangan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h3>Customer Request</h3>

<?php
    foreach ($results as $value) {
?>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td><?= $value['nama']?></td>
        <td><?= $value['phone']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $value['alamat_pengirim']?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

 <table class="table">
  <th>
   Alamat
  </th>
  <th>
   Tarif
  </th>

<?php        
     foreach ($undg[$value['req']] as $row) {        
?>
  <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['alamat_tujuan']?></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="<?php echo $row['excel_id']?>" name="tarif"></input> <!-- id input text nya harus dibedakan berdasarkan excel_id -->
        <?php form_open(); ?>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick=update(<?php echo $row['excel_id']?>)>Update Tarif
</button>
        </td>
        <?php form_close(); ?>
<?php }}; ?>
  </tr>
 </table>

</body>
</html>

<script>
function update(excel_id)    {

        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "<?php echo site_url('ajax/edit');?>/" + excel_id + "/" + $('#'+excel_id).val(),
         data: $(this).serialize(),
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); 
        }
        });
    };


</script>
```

i want to send the value '9000' which inside the input text into mysql. i don't know the syntax

Comment: so whats the actual question??

Comment: i get the value '9000' from ajax , and i want to send that value into a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
             $this->request->updatedata($excel_id,$tarif);
```

instead of

```
             $this->request->updatedata($tarif,$excel_id);
```